# Copy ctor with mutex as data member

Tags: c++, mutex

For classes with mutex as members, when I create the copy constructor, I need to decide which mutex to lock. For the following code, I am wondering why I only need to lock **rhs.mu_** but don't have to lock **this->mu_**? Could it be possible that the copy constructor being called by multiple threads for the same object?

```
class Obj {
 public:
  std::mutex mu_;
  std::string data_;

  // copy ctor
  Obj(const Obj& rhs) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(rhs.mu_); // why only lock rhs.mu_?
    data_ = rhs.data_;
  }
}
```

**Updates:**
Is this piece of code calling the copy ctor at the same time using **new**?

```
Obj* t = nullptr;
Obj someObj;

// ... populate someObj

std::thread t1([&]() { t = new Obj(someObj); });
std::thread t2([&]() { t = new Obj(someObj); });
```

Comment: How exactly do you envision a copy constructor -- or any constructor -- being called from multiple threads on the same object?  I suppose it's theoretically possible (I *think*) with placement new.   But you'd have to go out of your way for that

Comment: When copy constructor is called object is not created yet. So no other operation is called. That means we need not to lock this->mu_.

Comment: @CGD why? Assume I have two **other** objects B and C, thread1 wants to construct A from B, thread2 wants to construct A from C, without proper locking, A could be constructed half from B and half from C, right?

Comment: In that case I think you have bigger problems. Two threads constructing the same object at the same time doesn't seem like a good plan.

Comment: Two threads which are calling the copy constructor of a class: The original is mutex-safed - that's fine. What you didn't tell: how are the copy constructed instances stored. If they are `auto` (i.e. local variables) then no problem. (The instances are "thread-private".) If they are allocated by `new` it's similar. If these two instances are global (i.e. `static` or `extern`) then these are actually not two instances but one (except these were `thread_local`.) In this case, you have a problem. The same could be achieved by placement-new (as already mentioned).

Comment: In order to have a race condition, more than one thread must have the ability to read and/or write to the object at the same time.  This typically happens when two threads both hold a pointer (or a reference) to the same object, so that either thread access the object via that pointer/reference at any time.  But the thread creating the object won't typically have access to any pointer/reference to the object until after the object's constructor has finished executing, so the chances of it being able to share the object with another thread during its construction seem slim.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to construct the same object twice.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld "*Assume I have two **other** objects B and C, thread1 wants to construct A from B, thread2 wants to construct A from C, without proper locking, A could be constructed half from B and half from C, right?*" - no. Each thread constructs its own object independent of the other thread. Like any function, a constructor runs only in the thread that calls it. It is simply not possible to construct a single object across threads. Now, if both threads then assign their constructed object to the same variable A, you have a race condition on that variable, not on the constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to lock the mutex of the copied-from object (to make sure you're copying an object in a consistent state), while you can leave alone the lock of the object being constructed.

This is true in general for constructors: a constructor call is single-thread by definition:

- local variables are local to the current thread (as the stack is per-thread); an instance of them is constructed whenever a particular thread enters the relevant scope;
- thread local variables are thread local (duh), the construction of each thread local instance happens in the relevant thread;
- static storage duration variables (globals, `static` locals, `static` class fields) are guaranteed to be initialized once by the standard (the compiler injects something similar to `call_once`);
- objects allocated through "regular" `new` are, again, safe, as each thread running an expression like `new A` will allocate a different instance over which the constructor will run.

The only problem you can have is if some client of yours plays with placement `new`, but in that case I'd argue that it's the caller's responsibility not to call placement `new` constructor concurrently over the same object - as:

- even in the non concurrent case, calling placement `new` twice over the same memory location (without a destructor call in between) is a contract violation on your caller's part, so serializing through a mutex in your constructor would not solve anything;
- besides, a mutex instance member wouldn't solve anything, as you'd have a race condition anyway on the initialization of the mutex itself. To make it work you would need a global mutex, and you'd still not solve the point above.

So, long story short, don't worry about locking *the object being constructed* in construction. The language guarantees you that object construction is nonconcurrent.

Answer (score 4):

If your variable is local, it's unaccessible to other threads during construction, because other thread can't name a local variable in this thread.

If your variable has static lifetime, thread safety is guaranteed by C++ standard:

[[stmt.dcl]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl#4)

> Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage duration or thread storage duration is performed the first time control passes through its declaration;
>
> ...
>
> If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.

Thus the constructor won't be called twice.